# Export tables from data modeler to oracle database by sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I created logical and relational model in Oracle Datamodeler of my database and I would like add some examples data in tables. 
When I open sql developer and connect to my database - user(system). I don't know how to import created tables from relational model and how writing examples date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you design is 'finished' - you need to export your relational model as a SQL script.

[image: Press the button outlined in RED]

This will bring up a wizard where you can probably safely ignore a bunch of options - just press OK.

This will spit out a script.

```
-- Generated by Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler 4.1.0.873
--   at:        2015-05-22 05:39:15 EDT
--   site:      Oracle Database 11g
--   type:      Oracle Database 11g


CREATE TABLE TABLE_1
(
    Column_1 INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Column_2 BLOB ,
    Column_3 CHAR (4)
) ;

ALTER TABLE TABLE_1 ADD CONSTRAINT TABLE_1_PK PRIMARY KEY ( Column_1 ) ;
```

Open that in a SQL Developer connection with the USER you want the objects to live in - don't use SYSTEM or SYS! - and execute with F5.

Then refresh your table node, and you'll see your data.

The easiest way to add a bunch of sample data is to import it from an Excel file. That's pretty straightforward - Google it if you get stuck.